# Updating a Flex Mobile Application

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe, flex-mobile

Is updating a Flex Mobile Application done in the same way an Air application is updated?

Can't seem to find information specifically for mobile on this.

Apparently, if I trace out Updater.isSupported, it gives back false. From the Adobe documentation: The AIR update framework is only supported in the desktop profile. It is not supported for extended desktop applications (applications installed with a native installer), and it is not supported on the mobile profile (iPhone applications written with ActionScript 3.0). Check the Updater.isSupported property at runtime to see if the update framework is supported.

So how do you implement updates for Mobile Apps created with Flex (Android + iOs)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac-77bd3ea112e2c0a7ed0-8000.html gives a clear answer.

Comment: Thanks for the information. 
And concerning apps not distributed on the Android Market, do you find some information? I don't...

Comment: I think you can distribute them with mail or other platforms if they exist.